# Swift Package Manager C-interop: Non-system libraries

Tags: c, swift, interop, swift-package-manager

How can I use the Swift Package Manager to include C code (in my case, a single `.c` file and a header file) *without* requiring the user to install my C library into `/usr/local/lib`?

I had thought to create a Package in a subdirectory of my main package containing the header + lib, and use relative paths, and finally build with `swift build -Xlinker ./relative/path/to/mylib`, however I'm not having any success resolving the dependency since it's expected to be a standalone git repository. Error message is:

`error: failed to clone; fatal: repository '/absolute/path/to/mylib' does not exist`

Moreover it's not clear to me whether using the `-Xlinker` flag is the correct approach.

I can't use a bridging header with a pure SwiftPM approach and installing my library system-wide seems overkill as well as not very portable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have done that in [this project](https://github.com/bscothern/Once) on github. It replaces `pthread_once_t` by wrapping it in C and re-exposing it to swift. It was done as a fun exercise in getting around what Swift tries to limit you into since `pthread_once_t` and `dispatch_once` are not available directly.

Here is a trimmed down version the `Package.swift` file:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Once",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Once",
            targets: ["OnceC", "Once"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "OnceC",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources/OnceC"),
        .target(
            name: "Once",
            dependencies: ["OnceC"],
            path: "Sources/Swift"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "OnceTests",
            dependencies: ["Once"]),
        ]
)
```

You can easily replace the product library with an executable. The main part is that the product's targets needs to contain both the C and Swift targets needed to build.

Then in your targets section make the swift target lists the C target as a dependency.

---

You can learn more about the required layout for C targets in the SwiftPM Usage.md [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#c-language-targets)

### C language targets

The C language targets are similar to Swift targets except that the C language
libraries should contain a directory named `include` to hold the public headers.

To allow a Swift target to import a C language target, add a target
dependency in the manifest file. Swift Package Manager will
automatically generate a modulemap for each C language library target for these
3 cases:

- If `include/Foo/Foo.h` exists and `Foo` is the only directory under the
  include directory then `include/Foo/Foo.h` becomes the umbrella header.
- If `include/Foo.h` exists and `include` contains no other subdirectory then
  `include/Foo.h` becomes the umbrella header.
- Otherwise if the `include` directory only contains header files and no other
  subdirectory, it becomes the umbrella directory.

In case of complicated `include` layouts, a custom `module.modulemap` can be
provided inside `include`. SwiftPM will error out if it can not generate
a modulemap w.r.t the above rules.

For executable targets, only one valid C language main file is allowed i.e. it
is invalid to have `main.c` and `main.cpp` in the same target.

---

The only other important thing is how you actually do your `#import` in the C code once it is compiled as a compatible module. If you use the `import/Foo/Foo.h` organization you need to use `#include <Foo/Foo.h>` and if you do `import/Foo.h` you can use `#import "Foo.h"`.

Comment: Oh man this is awesome, thanks for the answer and sample project, exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: I'd you have any problems just ask here and I am happy to help keep all the info in one place.

Comment: I'm trying to move a project from Xcode to compile under Ubuntu, and consequently need to bring a bridging header into the package. It should be simple, but I can't find any approach to doing it. This seems the closest, but I'm still at a loss what to do. Is somehow packaging the includes into a separate library really necessary, and if so, how?

Comment: When you say bridging header do you mean an ObjC bridging header? If so those aren't supported. You will need an appropriate umbrella header or modulemap though.

Comment: Maybe someone find useful a [link to modulemap file syntax](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language)